# Thread locking / exclusive access improvements

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, locking, thread-safety, mutex

I have 2 threaded methods running in 2 separate places but sharing access at the same time to a list array object (lets call it **PriceArray**), the first thread **Adds** and **Removes** items from PriceArray when necessary (the content of the array gets updated from a third party data provider) and the average update rate is between 0.5 and 1 second.

The second thread only reads -for now- the content of the array every 3 seconds using a foreach loop (takes most items but not all of them).

To ensure avoiding the nasty `Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute` exception when the second thread loops through the array I have wrapped the add and remove operation in the first thread with `lock(PriceArray)` to ensure exclusive access and prevent that exception from occurring. The problem is I have noticed a performance issue when the second method tries to loop through the array items as most of the time the array is locked by the add/remove thread.

Having the scenario running this way, do you have any suggestions how to improve the performance using other thread-safety/exclusive access tactics in C# 4.0?

Thanks.

Comment: First off, do not use the array itself as the sync object. Define a dedicated sync object for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are many alternatives.

The best/easiest would be to switch to using an appropriate collection in [`System.Collections.Concurrent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).  These are all thread-safe collections, and will allow you to use them without managing your own locks.  They are typically either lock-free or use very fine grained locking, so will likely dramatically improve the performance impacts you're getting from the synchronization.

Another option would be to use [ReaderWriterLockSlim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) to allow your readers to not block each other. Since a third party library is writing this array, this may be a more appropriate solution.  It would allow you to completely block during writing, but the readers would not need to block each other during reads.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that ArrayList.Remove() takes most of the time, because in order to perform deletion it performs two costly things:

1. linear search: just takes elements one by one and compares with element being removed
2. when index of the element being removed is found - it shifts everything below it by one position to the left.

Thus every deletion takes time proportionally to count of elements currently in the collection.

So you should try to replace ArrayList with more appropriate structure for this task. I need more information about your case to suggest which one to choose.